# The merge statement conflicted with the foreign key while inserting self join tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys

I have two entities:

```
public class Header 
{
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int Id {get;set;} 
        public string RefNo { get; set; }           
        public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Detail> Detail { get; set; }
}

public class Detail 
{        
         [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
         [Key]
         public int Id {get;set;} 
         public int HeaderId { get; set; }
         public decimal Amount { get; set; } 
         public int? ParentDetailId { get; set; }     
         public virtual Detail ParentDetail { get; set; }
         public virtual ICollection<Detail> ChlidDetail { get; set; }            
}
```

If there is one header and multiple details with out child details it is working fine, but when trying to insert a `ChildDetail`, I get an error.

This is how I am trying to insert:

```
 Header hdr = new Header();
 hdr.RefNo = "Test";
 hdr.TotalAmount  = Convert.ToDecimal(5.3);
 hdr.Detail = new List<Detail>();
 hdr.Detail.Add(new Detail
                    {
                        HeaderId = hdr.Id,
                        Amount = 50,             
                        ParentDetail = null,            
                        ChlidDetail = new List<Detail>()
                    });

foreach(var dtl in hdr.Detail)
{
    dtl.ChlidDetail.Add(new Detail { HeaderId = hdr.Id, Amount = 25, ParentDetailId = dtl.Id });
}
```

After adding all entities called `context.SaveChanges()` and I get an error:

> The MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
> "FK_Detail_Header_HeaderId". The conflict occurred in database "XXXX",
> table "dbo.Header", column 'Id'

This is how the context code is there(using repository pattern)

here is the code snippet of context layer

```
internal readonly ApiContext context;
internal DbSet<T> entities;
string errorMessage = string.Empty;

public Repository(ApiContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        entities = context.Set<T>();
    }

    
 public T Insert(T entity)
   {
      if (entity == null)
         {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
         }
     entities.Add(entity);
     context.SaveChanges();
     return entity;          
   }
```

Comment: So you're obviously trying to insert a row into `Detail` that has a `HeaderId` which doesn't exist in the `Header` table ....

Comment: it works fine if public virtual ICollection<Detail> ChlidDetail is  null, but when inserting data to  ChlidDetail all get messed up. if I remove the foreach it works

Comment: @marc_s Both header and detail table id are autogenerated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes and it worked!

```
public class Detail 
{        
         [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
         [Key]
         public int Id {get;set;} 
         public int HeaderId { get; set; }
         public Header Header { get; set; }//change
         public decimal Amount { get; set; } 
         public int? ParentDetailId { get; set; }     
         public virtual Detail ParentDetail { get; set; }
         public virtual ICollection<Detail> ChlidDetail { get; set; }            
}

hdr.Detail.Add(new Detail
                    {
                        Header = dtohdr,//change
                        Amount = 50, 
                        ChlidDetail = new List<Detail>()
                    });

foreach(var dtl in hdr.Detail)
{
    dtl.ChlidDetail.Add(new Detail 
                            {
                                 Header = dtohdr,//change
                                 Amount = 25                               
                            });
}
```

assgined the Header entity to detail table then it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Since all your `Id` columns are autogenerated by the database - why are you setting them explicitly in your code? Plus: you're setting them to values that aren't even known yet (since they're only going to be assigned when you *actually save* your data).

Just **don't set** those Id columns and let the database handle the assigning of the values, and the "connecting" of the parent and child objects:

```
Header hdr = new Header();
hdr.RefNo = "Test";
hdr.TotalAmount  = Convert.ToDecimal(5.3);
hdr.Detail = new List<Detail>();

hdr.Detail.Add(new Detail
                    {
                        // don't use this!  HeaderId = hdr.Id,
                        Amount = 50,             
                        // don't use this!  ParentDetail = null,            
                        ChlidDetail = new List<Detail>()
                    });

foreach(var dtl in hdr.Detail)
{
    dtl.ChlidDetail.Add(new Detail 
                            {
                                 // don't use this! HeaderId = hdr.Id, 
                                 Amount = 25
                                 // don't use this either ParentDetailId = dtl.Id 
                            });
}
```

And btw: it should be **ChildDetail** - not "ChlidDetail" ......

Comment: Thanks for the expert advise, let me try

Comment: @Nighil : can you show us the setup code for the two entities? How are you relating those entities and their parent/child relationships?

Comment: The MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Detail_Header_HeaderId". The conflict occurred in database "XXXX", table "dbo.Header", column 'Id'

Comment: We need to see the **C# code** that defines your entities, in your `DbContext` file .....

Comment: @Nighil: you should have a class in your system that **derives from `DbContext`** - right? I need to see **that class** - it contains the **setup** of how these entities are connected - that's what I'm looking for in order to be able to possibly help .....

Comment: Thanks marc_s for the help, did you tried to replicate the issue? or is it working fine when tried?